# On click, display other data in separate div in d3.js; Passing by value

Tags: javascript, html, svg, d3.js

I am working on an undirected graph in d3. When I click a node, I want to display its data in a separate div (class: info) outside the svg. However, I can't figure out how to place the data from node to the div.

```
var node = svg.selectAll(".node")
              .data(graph.nodes)
              .enter().append("circle")
              .attr("class", "node")
              .attr("r", 5)
              .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
              .call(force.drag)
              .on("click", function(d){
                    d3.selectAll(".node").attr('r', 5)
                                         .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.group); })
                                         .style("stroke","none");       
                    d3.select(this).attr('r', 25)
                                   .style("fill","lightcoral")
                                   .style("stroke","red");

                    d3.select("#info").text(/* TEXT */);
                });
```

I tried:

1. I've tried `d3.select("#info").text(function(d){return d.text;});`. However, if I have understood correctly, `d` would refer to the data from the current selection. So, with this, there is no data inside `d3.select("#info")` since the current selection is the div `#info`.
2. I also tried getting binding `function(d){return d.text;}` to a variable, and passing that variable to `text()`. However, Javascript does not pass by value; it's the same scenario as #1.

I've read about creating an object just for the text. I think I have overlooked something here. Is there an elegant way to show the data from the node to a div outside the svg?

Comment: It sounds like it would be simply `d3.select("#info").text(d.text);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lars is right: `d3.select("#info").text(d.text);`

What you were doing, `d3.select("#info").text(function(d){return d.text;});`, by passing a function to .text() is to have that function evaluated in the context of the #info element you just selected. But you're already in the context of the node you want to get the text from, and the `d` you're accessing (in Lars's answer) is the `d` being passed to your click callback. So, as long as that `d` has the .text property you want, you should be in business.

Comment: My mistake. I quickly assumed that `d.text` would automatically convert to string all the data inside the node. There was no `text` field so that's why there was no string appended. Thank you. :)